# Can you continue synchronously after a Promise.All?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Lets say I have the following code:

```
var myData = [];

var future = Promise.All([getPromise1, getPromise2]).then((result)=>{
  var myData = result []
}).catch((err)=>{
  \\Do something with err
})

doSomething (myData);
```

Can I do something with myData after it has received the data from promise.all result? Or do I have to handle subsequent code inside of a promises .then().

For Example:

```
future.then((data)=>{
  doSomething(myData);
});
```

I feel like I would have to create a bunch of .then()'s in order to keep handling any  type of synchronous code. Although I suppose since myData is the result then any code that uses the data in result should be handled as part of that promise like:

```
var future = Promise.All([getPromise1, getPromise2]).then((result)=>{
  doSomething(result [])
}).catch((err)=>{
  \\Do something with err
})
```

Am I just understanding this all wrong?
Looking forward to thoughts and opinions!

P.S im working on node.js

Comment: You can put your synchronous stuff into a function, so you need to call *then(yourFunction)* only once.

Comment: short answer is no, because asynchronous code is always asynchronous - long answer is, you can make your code look like you want, using async/await - see https://jsfiddle.net/4ghfdjcy/ - or perhaps more correctly https://jsfiddle.net/4ghfdjcy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the result of the promise can only be used within the promise's .then.

Side note - subsequent promises don't necessarily need to be nested, instead they can be chained. For example:

```
myPromise(foo).then(bar => {
    // Do something with the result
    baz = bar * 2

    // Pass the result to some other promise
    return mySecondPromise(baz)
}).then(foo2 => {
    // Output the result of the second promise
    console.log(foo2)
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

Errors will propagate down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle subsequent code inside the `.then()` function callback. The reason you can't do anything outside of the promise chain is because of the way Promises work. a quick Google search about asynchronous javascript gives [an explanation](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) of why this is. The short answer is that `doSomething(myData)` will run before the code in the `.then()` function is run, which means that myData will still be an empty array when the script reaches that point in the code.

Actually even if the code did somehow reach the `.then()` function before the `doSomething(myData)` method, myData would still be an empty array because the myData declared in the `.then()` function is another variable entirely, since it is declared as

```
var myData
```

If you want to write code that *looks* more synchronous, I suggest using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), depending on if your version of node.js supports it or if you're using a transpiler. With async/await your code would look like:

```
async function() {
    try {
        var myData = await Promise.all([getPromise1, getPromise2]);
        doSomething(myData);
    } catch (ex) {
        // Do something with err
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but var myData has a global scope. If the Promise.All resolved then .then((result)) can be placed in myData and then continued synchronously from there to execute doSomething(myData)

Comment: I think you mean myData can be placed in the .then(result => {...}) callback? And yes you'll just need to remove the 'var' keyword before myData inside the callback to reference the global myData object.

Comment: I didn't even notice that extra var. Thanks.